# HTA application: Place window at the bottom-right of the screen

Tags: javascript, vbscript, position, hta

I'm trying to move my hta application window to the bottom-right of my desktop (screen). If I put static values, then It works but I want to place the window at the bottom-right for every screen resolution. I don't know how to say to the .hta "place the window 50% from the top border and 5% from the right border". Here's my little script:

```
<script language="VBScript">
   'On Error Resume Next
   window.resizeTo 450, 400
   var monitorHeight = screen.Height;
   var monitorWidth = screen.Width; 

    window.moveTo monitorWidth-450, monitorHeight-400



    window.moveTo WindowLeft,WindowTop 

</script>
```

I can center the window:

```
<script language="VBScript">
  'On Error Resume Next   
  window.resizeTo 450, 400
window.moveTo (screen.width -450) / 2, (screen.height-400) / 2
</script>
```

But can't put the window at the bottom-right.

Comment: If the window shall be positioned to bottom-right, you can't use WindowTop and WindowLeft.
If window.moveTo sets the top-left windowcorner, Bottom-right would be: `window.moveTo  monitorWidth-WindowWidth, monitorHeight-WindowHeight`

Comment: Thank you very much, still not working. Now the window is at the top-left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like that :

```
<script language="VBScript">
    window.resizeTo 450,400
    WindowLeft = (window.screen.availWidth - 450)  
    WindowTop  = (window.screen.availHeight - 400)
    window.moveTo WindowLeft, WindowTop
</script>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :)) easy, clean and understandable. Thank you very much!